# Search NFS network volume from OS X client

Tags: macos, search, nfs, cluster

I asked: How does a Mac OSX SL or Lion user search the cluster for a particular file (foo.txt)

> From the cluster, you would need to run some form of recursive lookup for the file desired. As an example, using 'find'.
>
> ```
> RAM-1# find /ifs |grep test.txt
> /ifs/Elements/avid2test.txt
> /ifs/Elements/test.txt
> ```
>
> I would suggest contacting Apple support regarding their recommendation for searching for files on remote file systems from the Mac client itself

That's great, but I don't want users using CLU!

Anyone know a good non-CLI method? Spotlight is not an option. The cluster is roughly 80 TB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better command would be

```
find /ifs -name "test.txt" -print
```

The OSX simple Find from the Finder unfortunately uses Spotlight and needs an index to be created first - so will not work in your case.

For a GUI look at programs like [EasyFind](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12)

But with 80TB - well really more the number of files - searching will take a long time - might it not be better to provide some form of indexing ather than use raw search.

There are also commercial searching solutions like [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/) which is a program and/or dedicated server that runs in your site.

Comment: `find /ifs |grep test.txt` *is* Unix?! (It's just not very beautiful..)

Comment: Thanks very much! Works like a charm and is surprisingly fast...!